# Returning a string that has been span styled in a function

Tags: php

My function is supposed to accept two parameters: `$message`, which is just a string of words, and `$color`, which is a string with a color name.

I want to make it so that the color in variable `$color` is added to `$message` and the final result returned would be a `span` style with the color applied to the message.  I've been looking online for a solution but have had no luck. Here is the code so far. What am I missing?

```
function speak($message,$color) {
    //supposed to convert $message into <span style='color:$color;'>$message</span>
    return "$message$color";
};

//red as the span style color
$red="red";

//message that will accept span style
$mess="Hello World";

//invoke function speak to style them both
$total=speak($mess,$red);

//output total
echo $total;
```

Comment: You already seem to have the answer in the comment in your function...

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, the comment in your code already says what the function should do:

```
//supposed to convert $message into <span style='color:$color;'>$message</span>
```

So, let's turn that into an actual statement:

```
return "<span style='color:$color;'>$message</span>";
```

Woah, not so fast! You're supposed to return *valid* HTML, so you must properly escape the variables; there are various ways to do this, but I prefer to use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
return sprintf('<span style="color: %s;">%s</span>',
    htmlspecialchars($color, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
    htmlspecialchars($message, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
);
```

See also: [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)

Btw, inline CSS should be avoided; more often than not, classes are the preferred approach.

Comment: What about urlencoded strings?  And non UTF-8 characters? Or php tags in the string?

Comment: @7stud What about them? Are you saying they need special treatment?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

You only need to put this line of code into a variable or directly return it:

`$mes = "<span style='color:$color;'>$message</span>";`

Code:

```
function speak($message,$color) {
 //supposed to convert $message into <span style='color:$color;'>$message</span>
 $mes = "<span style='color:$color;'>$message</span>";
 return $mes;
 };
 //red as the span style color
 $red="red";
 //message that will accept span style
 $mess="Hello World";
 //invoke function speak to style them both
 $total=speak($mess,$red);
 //output total
 echo $total;
```

Comment: AHhh that worked thanks a lot. I tried it before but was missing the double quotes around span.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is. Like you said, you're missing something easy:

```
function speak($message,$color) {
  return "<span style='color:$color;'>$message</span>";
 };
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

function speak($message, $color) {

return <<<END_OF_HTML
<span style="color:$color;">$message</span>
END_OF_HTML;

}

echo speak("hello", "blue");

?>

--output:--
<span style="color:blue;">hello</span>
```

Comment: How about `echo speak('', 'hello"><script>alert("hello");</script>');`?

Comment: If that's what the caller wants, that's what the caller gets.